# Android Outofmemoryerror?

Tags: java, android

I have these codes for my android activity. But it gave me java.lang.outofmemoryerror: java.lang.string[] of length 2131492864 ecxeeds the VM limit. I want to know if there is something wrong with my codes or is it my String.xml contains too much items? Or there's too many pictures? I have around 120 150x150 image that is around 20kb each. If possible I would like to know how can i solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

```
public class ChampionInfo extends FragmentActivity {

GridView gridtable;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_champion_info);

    gridtable = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridtable);
    gridtable.setAdapter(new GridAdapter(this));
}

public class GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    String[] list = new String[R.array.championlist];

    int[] champImage = getImage();

    public int[] getImage() {
        int[] tempImage = new int[list.length];

        for (int i = 0; i > list.length; i++) {
            tempImage[i] = getResources().getIdentifier(list[i],
                    "drawable", getPackageName());
        }

        return tempImage;

    }

    // Constructor
    public GridAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return champImage.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);

        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        imageView.setImageResource(champImage[position]);
        return imageView;
    }

    // Keep all Images in array

}
```

}

These are the error that shows on the catlog:

> 09-26 06:09:38.869: E/AndroidRuntime(2653): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   09-26 06:09:38.869: E/AndroidRuntime(2653): Process: com.example.loldb, PID: 2653
>   09-26 06:09:38.869: E/AndroidRuntime(2653): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: java.lang.String[] of length 2131492864 exceeds the VM limit
>   09-26 06:09:38.869: E/AndroidRuntime(2653):     at com.example.loldb.ChampionInfo$GridAdapter.(ChampionInfo.java:50)
>   09-26 06:09:38.869: E/AndroidRuntime(2653):     at com.example.loldb.ChampionInfo.onCreate(ChampionInfo.java:44)
>   09-26 06:09:38.869: E/AndroidRuntime(2653):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
>   09-26 06:09:38.869: E/AndroidRuntime(2653):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>   09-26 06:09:38.869: E/AndroidRuntime(2653):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
>   09-26 06:09:38.869: E/AndroidRuntime(2653):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
>   09-26 06:09:38.869: E/AndroidRuntime(2653):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
>   09-26 06:09:38.869: E/AndroidRuntime(2653):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
>   09-26 06:09:38.869: E/AndroidRuntime(2653):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>   09-26 06:09:38.869: E/AndroidRuntime(2653):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>   09-26 06:09:38.869: E/AndroidRuntime(2653):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
>   09-26 06:09:38.869: E/AndroidRuntime(2653):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   09-26 06:09:38.869: E/AndroidRuntime(2653):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>   09-26 06:09:38.869: E/AndroidRuntime(2653):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>   09-26 06:09:38.869: E/AndroidRuntime(2653):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
>   09-26 06:09:38.869: E/AndroidRuntime(2653):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: can you add the exception stacktrace as well

Comment: In which drawable directories did you place your images?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line doesn't make much sense:

```
String[] list = new String[R.array.championlist];
```

R.array.championlist is an integer that points to the what I assume is a string array resource. You can load that string array with [Resources.getStringArray(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getStringArray%28int%29).

```
String[] list = resources.getStringArray(R.array.championlist);
```

Comment: I tried it but it gives me error with the keyword "resources", I even tried to directly copy and paste it.

Comment: I meant a Resources object. You can get one from the Context with getResources().

Comment: Ok Thanks for the help it fixed the not enough memory error, but now it gives me a nullpointerexception.

Comment: Is the context null? It looks like you're not setting mContext.

Comment: Sorry I'm still kind of new with the Context stuff. This is my first attempt with android apps. So If its possible can you educate me a little with this?

Comment: Also I realize my app is crashing during this line of code.
    gridtable.setAdapter(new GridAdapter(this));